# Are the new async and await keywords in ES7 copied from C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2016

Noticing that async and await aren't found in Java, where these new keywords in ES7 copied from the C# language?  I'm curious as to the origin:  Who proposed the keyword names and is someone in the JS community is leveraging concepts from the .NET framework?

Comment: These concepts *long* predate C#'s implementation of them.  There are lots of other languages that had similar language features that C# based their implementation off of.  Also, they're *language* features, they're not features of the .NET framework.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The concept of using promises (or futures, etc.) is becoming more and more popular, but it isn't new. You can find it in MultiLisp for example.

The `async` and `await` keywords however were used recently in C# and now are spreading into many other languages.

> Several mainstream languages now have language support for futures and promises, most notably popularized by the `async` and `await` constructions in .NET 4.5 (announced 2010, released 2012) largely inspired by the asynchronous workflows of F#, which dates to 2007. This has subsequently been adopted by other languages, notably Dart (2014), Python (2015), Hack (HHVM), and drafts of ECMAScript 7 (JavaScript), Scala, and C++.

So yes, JS is borrowing from C#.

From [Futures and promises#History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises#History)